# Закрыть страницы для авторизированных пользователей

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3

Подскажите в чем проблема. Хочу закрыть доступы для авторизированных пользователей на страницы для логина и регистрации. **Symfony version 3.1.3**

```
security:
encoders:
    App\AppBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: sha512
        encode-as-base64: true
        iterations: 10

providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: AppBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: /.*
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login/
        logout: true
        security: true
        anonymous: true
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /
```

Добавляем на эти страницы `access_control`

```
access_control:
    - { path: /signup/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /login/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Не работает. Ладно, добавим еще такую штуку

```
access_control:
   - { path: /signup/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
   - { path: /login/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

И вроде как все ок, но при переходе на /login/ входит в циклическую переадресацию, а при переходе на  /signup/ идет редирект на /login/ и опять идет циклическая переадресация.

Работает только тогда, когда добавим в action

```
if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
}
```

Проблема в том, что я хочу задавать доступы в security.yml и, думаю, так будет правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **TL;DR:**: Если нет желания использовать явные ограничения в паре-тройке экшенов, можно глянуть на [использование expression language для описания ограничений](http://symfony.com/doc/current/expressions.html#security-expression-variables), либо реализовать [VoterInterface](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) с нужной логикой.

---

## Почему не сработал набор правил описанный в вопросе?

#### Рассмотрим сильно упрощенную схему работы access_control.

- Каждый запрос сопоставляется со списком правил доступа `access_control`. Если удалось сопоставить запрос с одним из правил, к данному запросу будут применены ограничения описанные в этом правиле, и дальнейшая обработка списка прекращается (first win).
- Если результат проверки предыдущего шага оказывается не удовлетворительным (нет нужной роли, не та схема запроса, ограничения по IP и пр.), бросается внутреннее исключение `AccessDeniedException`.
- При возникновении исключения `AccessDeniedException` система попытается аутентифицировать пользователя выполнив редирект на `login_path`, если пользователь еще не выполнил вход, либо вернет HTTP ошибку с кодом 403 в случае если пользователь залогинен, но не авторизован использовать данный ресурс.

---

> **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY** - *данный атрибут имеют пользователи, попавшие в зону ответственности фаервола, но еще не выполнившие процедуру логина. Часто используется для гарантированного доступа к ресурсам.*
>
> **IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY** - *таким атрибутом обладают пользователи, предоставившие данные для аутентификации в течение текущей сессии. Этот атрибут включает в себя предыдущий*

---

Между двумя описанными атрибутами существует еще один: `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`, но пока не будем заострять на нем внимание.

Теперь давайте глянем на вашу первую конфигурацию:

```
access_control:
    - { path: /signup/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /login/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Здесь гарантирован доступ к ресурсам /signup/ и /login/ для всех без исключения пользователей. Это не работает как вы ожидаете, но работает как описано в документации: любой пользователь может попасть на страницу логина и регистрации.

Затем вы меняете атрибуты доступа:

```
access_control:
    - { path: /signup/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: /login/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Так, как анонимный пользователь считается авторизованным анонимно (пускай и с самым низким уровнем доступа), получаем противоречивое условие: пользователь аутентифицирован и пользователь не аутентифицирован (атрибут IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY включает в себя и IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY).

> По описанным выше причинам получим циклический редирект: для урлов логина и регистрации пользователь всегда будет считаться не авторизованным (независимо от фактического контекста) и будет предпринята попытка редиректа на все тот же /login/.

Затем вы добавляете в контроллере:

```
if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
    throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
}
```

На этот раз проверка происходит в контексте аутентифицированного пользователя, и ожидаемо работает.